# Find the corresponding date to the last cell in a column that has a value of two out of three available options

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with chronological dates on the left column and multiple other columns (not immediately following) that give me the "results" (S=Successful, P=Partially Successful, F=Failed) of different data uploads based on the numbers I enter each day - if no upload was attempted the cell is left blank.

Above the table in each of the multiple "results" columns I would like to have the date appear that corresponds to the last row (day) that a "P" OR an "S" appears in that column.

I've searched and read about Index(match()) formulas, but I haven't seen anything about matching multiple criteria.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/last_value.php

I tried using the OR function within the MATCH and it didn't seem to work.  Another site mentioned using the SUMPRODUCT function, but again, I could not figure out how to fit in multiple criteria into the formula.

http://www.exceluser.com/explore/last-item-in-list.htm
- Also (and I don't know if this matters) but this example references the column header of a table within the formula, and I can't figure out how to apply that to my situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LOOKUP`, for example this formula will find the last "P" or "S" (or "p" or "s", it's not case-sensitive) in `B2:B1000`.....and return the corresponding date from `A2:A1000`.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((B2:B1000="P")+(B2:B1000="S")),$A2:$A1000)`

Note: I assume that the dates are in ascending order and that the "last" date positionally (furthest down) is also the latest in which case you could also use an "array formula" like this:

`=MAX(IF((B2:B1000="S")+(B2:B1000="P"),$A2:$A1000))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: That first formula worked perfectly!  Thank you!!!!  I'll have to look further into the LOOKUP function.  I use VLOOKUP all of the time, but not LOOKUP.  I couldn't get the 2nd formula to work, but I didn't really need it after the first one worked, I was just trying for curiosity's sake.  Thanks!!!